# Lydia is bugged

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I was in the middle of building my house when I was disconnected from Xbox live. Now when I go to Lydia she is always facing one way and when I talk to her she tries to move but she doesn't. Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: have you tried loading from a previous save?

Comment: When in doubt, use the Wabbajack. Make sure you save prior to doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Reload an old save.

It's always, *always* useful to keep old saves around.

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading a previous save or if that doesn't work then tell Lydia to go home (Dragonsreach, Whiterun) and then go and get her there, she should move fine after that.